# How to get uploaded image from s3 using parse server

Tags: ios, mongodb, heroku, amazon-s3, parse-server

I have manually uploaded images to my S3 bucket.  I would like to use them in my parse server IOS app.  I set up files Adapter in my parse sever, but can't seem to get the correct url in my app.  The url that is coming in from AFNetworking herokuapp.com/parse/files...  If I upload images directly to my S3 bucket, do the urls need to be a certain format?  My app does not require any images to be uploaded, it just gets data from mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the url of the S3 image into the database on Parse and reference the parse database element as a string.  Then you should be able to use UIImage(url: url)